# How to recover password in Solaris on vmware

Tags: solaris

I have Solaris 11 installed on VMware workstation 10 and I forgot my login password. I tried a lot but not able to login.

How can I recover the Solaris 11 login password installed on VMware 10 workstation. Can I do it with the help of ISO image of OS?

Comment: does this help? https://solarisway.wordpress.com/2013/06/15/reset-solaris-11-root-password/

Answer (score 4):

Solaris will ask you for privileged user credentials when entering single user mode. In Solaris 11 the root user is by default a role and you can not use it to logon, even within single user mode. If you lost your user credentials you can recover from this by the following procedure:

- Reboot from Solaris 11 installation media
- Choose option 3 to enter a shell
- Import the root pool from the installed copy of Solaris
- Find the current boot environment
- Modify the shadow file (ie. change password field to value from known user account or from local account) in the imported pool
- Reboot again

Sample:

```
zpool import -fNR /a rpool
beadm list # get BE name with R flag
zfs mount rpool/ROOT/solaris-11 # solaris-11 is BE name
cp /a/etc/shadow /a/etc/shadow.bak
vi /a/etc/shadow # make modifications
zpool export rpool
reboot
```

Another possibility, when you know the root password, is to change the root role into a normal user. Instead of modifying `/a/etc/shadow`, modify `/a/etc/user_attr` and change `type=role` to `type=normal`